# Django query based on foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I have two models, a Project and an Action:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Project Name", max_length=200, unique = True)

class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Action Name", max_length=200)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Project")
    notes = models.TextField("Notes", blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Complete?")
    status = models.IntegerField("Action Status", choices = STATUS, default=0)
```

I need a query that returns all the Projects for which there are no actions with status < 2.

I tried:

```
Project.objects.filter(action__status__gt = 1)
```

But this returns all the Projects because in each Project, there are some actions with status 2 and some actions with status less than 2.  Also, it repeated Projects in the resulting query.  My current solution is below:

```
Project.objects.filter(action__status__gt =1).exclude(action__status__lt =2).annotate()
```

This collapses the repeating results and shows only actions with action statuses greater than 1.  But is this the correct way to construct such a query?  What if I wanted to return Projects with actions statuses greater than 1 OR Projects with no actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your requirement, but I think you can do that using annotations.

`Project.objects.annotate(m = Min('action__status')).filter(Q(m = None) | Q(m__gt = 1))`

The SQL generated is:

```
SELECT
    "testapp_project"."id", "testapp_project"."name", 
    MIN("testapp_action"."status") AS "m" 
FROM "testapp_project" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "testapp_action" ON ("testapp_project"."id" = "testapp_action"."project_id") 
GROUP BY "testapp_project"."id", "testapp_project"."name" 
HAVING(
       MIN("testapp_action"."status") IS NULL 
    OR MIN("testapp_action"."status") > 1 
)
```

Which is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Django's ORM is not capable of expressing this. You will need to use a raw query in order to perform this.

Comment: thanks.  I see why that's probably true.  Have any advice about how to build this raw query?